# Подсеть одного айпи нагружает сервер, как защититься

Tags: linux, apache, centos, ddos, vesta

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Имеется сервер с установленной VestaCP на CentOS. Последнее время начал замечать, что сервер переодически начинает нагружаться и было принято решение поставить на apache – mod_status.

В итоге, насколько я понимаю, mod_status показывает что сервер зафлудили? Как от этого можно защититься автоматически? Сейчас забанил пул айпи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читайте, что такое `iptables`

Comment: Или добавить ключ в API или авторизацию.

Comment: @And идею понял, но правильно ли я понимаю, это – http флуд?

Answer (score 3):

Во первых, можно поднять [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/)

Во вторых, можно получать курлом список активных коннектов, вычислять ip/подсети флудеров и просто закрыть этим ip/подсетям доступ. Например так

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 159.138.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Удалить можно будет потом так:
1. Сначала ищем номер правило, нам нужен номер строки, первый столбец

```
iptables -L --line-numbers
```

2. Потом удаляем:

```
iptables -D INPUT Номерправила
```

Comment: Fail2ban по-дефолту стоит, по нему и банил пул) Но правильно ли я понимаю, это – HTTP флуд?

Comment: Это может быть и индексация сайта, и выкачивание его, и флуд.